# Isomorphism between multiplicative and additive groups of reals

Tags: group-isomorphism

Consider:

• $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 0\}, \cdot)$

• $(\mathbb{R}_+, \cdot )$

• $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_2, +)$, where for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ and all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}_2$ we define $(x, a) + (y, b) =
(x + y, a + b).$

You may assume that these are all groups.

(a) Are the groups $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 0\}, ·)$ and $(\mathbb{R}_+, ·)$ isomorphic? Explain why / why not.

(b) Show that the groups $(\mathbb{R}\setminus 0, ·)$ and $(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_2, +)$ are isomorphic.
Hint: Your task is to find (with proof ) a bijection $f : \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ that satisfies
$f(x) + f(y) = f(x \cdot y)$ for all $x, y \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

I've been given these 2 questions for homework but I'm struggling quite a bit with them. Thanks to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: Why on earth would one use the symbols "R6=0" to denote the set of nonzero reals? Yes, we can define anything to mean anything we want, but making this choice in a halfway reasonable way is still important for actually _communicating_ ideas to people...

Comment: With sane notation, however: $(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}, \times)$ contains an element of order $2$; $(\mathbb R_+, \times)$ doesn't.

Comment: Perhaps R6=0 was meant to be $R^{\ne0}$, a notation I have been known to use.